# Simple list of applicants webapp

Tags: web-services, web, go, architecture

I am creating a web application that lists applicants and their position on a waiting list.

We need to be able to add new applicants to this list and remove applicants from the list. There will be under 10k applicants in the list.

**Specifics:**

- I plan to write the app in Golang.
- The list needs to be safe, I the program shuts down, it should be recoverable.
- The app should contain this data for every applicant: Name, Student ID, position.

**Questions:**

1. How do I secure the list (lock?) so it is updated correctly for both if two updates to it is made at the same time?
2. Should I save the data in a database or use a file?

I need your help!

**UPDATE:**

**Mockup code:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/boltdb/bolt"
)

type applicant struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    StudentID string
    Position  int
}

type priorityList struct {
    sync.Mutex
    applicants []applicant
}

func (l *priorityList) newApplicant(fn string, ln string, sid string) error {

    // add applicant to priorityList
    return nil
}

func (l *priorityList) removeApplicant(sid string) error {
    // remove applicant from priorityList
    return nil
}

func (l *priorityList) editApplicant(sid string) error {
    // edit applicant in priorityList
    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Database
    db, err := bolt.Open("priorityList.db", 0600, &bolt.Options{Timeout: 1 * time.Second})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a file, you could use a [`Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) to block concurrent writes.

Otherwise a database would be fine. For example [BoltDB](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) could be suitable. It is pure go and runs withing your program.

Comment: Doesn't BoltDB hold the data in memory? If so, the data will be lost if the program quits, right?

Comment: BoltDB stores the data on the disk.

Comment: I've updated my question with some code. What do you think? Is it correct to put the mutex in the list instead of the individual applicant?

Comment: If you use BoltDB you don't need a Mutex. Bolt internally handles the locking and unlocking. You only need a Mutex if you use files on your own.

Comment: Should I even use a `prioryList` struct as above or should I modify the data directly in the database?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches. You can use file and protect it with Go mutex or system lock. You can memory map the file for performance. You either can use BoltDB which is nice peace of software and provide needed machinery and can work in-process. If you write rare and mostly read, then constant DB https://github.com/colinmarc/cdb also looks interesting.
But, classic SQL DB has some advantages

- You can use third party store for data and easely migrate when needed
- You can access your data from third party app or just plain SQL
  request
- You can think about data schema and code logic separately